# Properly display CSS fonts in Chinese browser

Tags: css, browser, encoding

I've come across an issue where some custom fonts I've imported via CSS aren't displaying properly in Chinese language browsers.

For example, when I've installed a Chinese version of Chrome, the fonts come out larger than usual. What should I do to set it so that the fonts are displayed like in English browsers?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify - we're still talking about "English" (ASCII, western) characters here, not Chinese ones, correct?

Comment: Yea English characters

Comment: Nope, but very interesting question, +1

Comment: Could you show some css you are using?

Comment: umm just normal `font-size: 8px;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:lang` pseudo class to target a specific language in css.

So for example you could add `lang="en"` in the html tag.

Then in CSS:

```
:lang(en) body
{
    font-size: ...;
}
```

Comment: I've looked it up your suggested method and the thing is, it seems that selector is used to display different font properties for different languages on a site. My problem is the same language, English, being rendered differently on different language browsers/operatin systems.

Comment: Oh, hmmm did you check the inspector tools of the Chinese browser that, in fact the font-sizes are exactly the same as in the English version browser?

Comment: no actually it's one size bigger, 9px instead of 8px. But the weird thing is, I'm testing the same site, one on a Chinese Chrome in Mac in Chinese and one in a English Chrome in Mac in English. In the English chrome I'm able to quickly change font size and preview it with developer tools. In the Chinese chrome even after I've changed the font-size nothing happens in the preview...

Comment: then this sounds more like an issue with the Chinese browser rather than a problem with your code

Comment: Is that it? I'm testing a few other browsers on a Chinese windows system and it doesn't seem to reproduce this error. Also Safari on Mac in Chinese doesn't have this issue either. I'm relieved to hear this. But you'd expect that a browser developed by none other than Google should have this kind of small bug sorted out by now.  Anyway cheers!

Comment: hey, I don't know for sure, but it *sounds* that that. I would suggest to play around with font size, perhaps with !important and see if there are any changes